# Coroutine does not executed after delay in view model

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I need to execute some postponed action in ViewModel, so I write the following:

```
fun doAction() {
    viewModelScope.launch() {
        delay(3000)
        Log.i("Tag", "I can not see this message")
        // some actions...
    }
}
```

It prints the message if I keep this activity open. But if I close the activity within 3 sec it does not print anything.

Comment: `ViewModel`'s lifecycle is tied to the relevant Fragment/Activity, it is cleared when you quit your activity & all operations are cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

As @DarShan said after close activity, viewModel will clear and all the actions that depend on ViewModel will cancel, but if you want an action that does not depend on this ViewModel and this activity, you have to use `ProcessLifecycleOwenr`.
Add `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.1` to apps `build.gradle` file and then  use

```
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycleScope.launch{
  delay(3000)
  Log.i("Tag", "I can not see this message")
}
```